# Drag a file into a gui using PySide

Tags: python-3.x, pyside

Hi I want to drag a file (image) into my gui with PySide, however I can't get it to work. I Cannot get it to go into the dropEvent Function. My object that I am trying to drag into is a QGraphicsView so  the filter can't take over the whole gui because I want to drag two images into it.

```
class Consumer(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QComboBox, QtGui.QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.paylod = None
        super(Consumer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.chkApplyCompression.stateChanged.connect(self.makecompress)
        self.viewCarrier1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.viewCarrier1.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewCarrier1)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.QDropEvent and
            print('yay?')
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)





    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print("yay")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Yay!!")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    currentApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    currentForm = Consumer()
    currentForm.show()
    currentApp.exec_()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the drag enter event before Qt will handle a subsequent drop event:

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    event.accept()
```